# Codename One WebBrowser loading HTML from FileSystemStorage

Tags: html, codenameone, base-url

I am developing an app in Codename one for viewing of reports offline which come in a HTML format with resources contained in a separate folder. The application downloads the HTML and copies the folder structure of the resources as they are reference in the HTML. When I open the Report with a normal browser and point it to the "/.cn1" folder it loads and displays correctly. When using the simulator, HTML is loaded into the Codename One Web Browser object and is displayed (I can see the title of the report), it's just that the Web Browser is not loading any of the resources. I have also set the Base URL to the folder.

```
    WebBrowser wbBrowser = (WebBrowser) findByName("WebBrowser",  f);
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    wbBrowser.setPage(getTextFromFile(fs.getAppHomePath() + "/Reports/Report_2.html"), fs.getAppHomePath() + "/Reports/Report_2_files_files");
```

This is the code I am currently using. which runs after the Report Viewer form is shown. I have opened the report on the Default browser and Mozilla Firefox Android app in Android Lollipop and it displays the webpage correctly with all images and CSS included so I'm not sure if it is a codename one security issue. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : I have tried to simplify the app and am just running the below code;

```
        WebBrowser wbBrowser = (WebBrowser) findByName("WebBrowser", Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
        FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        fs.mkdir(fs.getAppHomePath() + "[Folder Name]");
        Util.downloadUrlToFile("http://[IpAddress]/mobile/admin/Report_2.html", fs.getAppHomePath() + "[Folder Name]/Report_2.html", true);
        if (FileSystemStorage.getInstance().exists(fs.getAppHomePath() + "[Folder Name]/Report_2.html") == true) {
            wbBrowser.setURL(fs.getAppHomePath() + "[Folder Name]/Report_2.html");
            Dialog.show("Success", "File has been downloaded and shown as " + wbBrowser.getTitle(), "Ok", "");
        } 
        else {
            Dialog.show("Failiure", "File has not been downloaded", "Ok", "");
        }
```

When run on an Android Lollipop device, the success dialog is displayed despite me not finding them when running a search on the device (I don't know where codename one stores files are stored). No other code is running anywhere on the device but I have had success when the storing the HTML document myself on the device and using a hardcoded reference (i.e `/Storage/emulated/0/Android/data/Report_2.html`). wbBrowser.getTitle() is null/"" when ran on the device. although when this line of code was somewhere else it became about:page. The HTML of Report_2.html is;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like your HTML file is invalid and missing the html tag. Mobile browsers are notoriously sensitive to valid html...

Comment: Apologies, this was hand copied from the file by hand. The real file is valid. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: When you write `[Folder Name]` you don't literally use `[Folder Name]` right? You use a valid name that's purely alphanumeric right?

Comment: No, [Folder Name] is just a placeholder for the real folder name, which is a company name that is alphanumeric with no special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days, I realised that `setURL()` requires a path in the format of `file://pathname`, I was using `/pathname`, which didn't work on `setURL()` but did on `setPage()` when I read the HTML from the file. This was a User Error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on the device but might point incorrectly on the simulator.

The path it should point at within the simulator is `file://home/appName/` which should work just fine. I suggest setting the URL to a file instead of setting the HTML which would allow you to easily add images, css files etc. not to mention that it would probably be faster.

Comment: Hi @Shai, thanks for your response. I have been working on the App today and have found that the simulator points to "file://home/" when fs.getAppHomePath() is used and not "file://home/[appName]", but it is storing and reading the HTML file correctly. setURL() did not show anything on the simulator interestingly despite the path being identical.

Comment: ...When the application is run on an Android device the path it points to it **/data/data/[com.myCompany.myApp]** which is not a path present on the device. Therefore when I try and read the file from the device I run into I/O errors, so I think that you are correct that it is a filepath error. To add, I am downloading files using `Util.downloadUrlToFile(serverFile, phoneFile, true);` where the phoneFile path is set with the `getAppHomePath()` function.

Comment: You should always use the `getAppHome` method to construct the path and effectively ignore how the URL looks.

Comment: I have taken your suggestions on-board @Shai and stuck with the getAppHome() function, but I was able to get the Report to view with images/CSS when hard coded. My question has been updated to show my efforts. In the new application the webBrowser showed a blank page. The test device is an LG G3 with an SD card. Can I ask why I cannot see the path in file Explorer even though `exists()` says it exists, is that a multiple platform issue?

Comment: So success dialog is shown but you don't see hello world on the screen?

Comment: That is correct, the webBrowser shows a blank screen.

Comment: I have confirmed that wbBrowser points to the correct component by setting the HTML using `setPage("<h1>Hello World Before</h1>", null);`, this works correctly. But is not changed when `setURL()` is used.

Comment: Update @Shai, It does work by using static paths pointing to **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/** rather than `getAppHome()` because it was pointing to a path that wasn't on the device (Do I have to create the path?), and when I tried to read the file it would error out, I know this is the desired way but it didn't work for me despite a few days of attempts, I am also manually writing to the disk rather than using `Util.downloadUrlToFile()` which would return successful despite the file not being on the device (Or not being readable).

Comment: I am still having the issue with the webBrowser not showing images but does show the text in the HTML. When `setURL()` is used it doesn't show anything. When open through another browser all images are shown. `Util.downloadUrlToFile()` does work when used with a static path, it just produces errors on the simulator for not using `getAppHome()`.

Comment: I have found what the problem was here. `setURL()` requires the line format to be `file://[path]` and I was putting the path as `/[path]`. This was confusing as the webBrowser did show text but no images. Anyways. the question has been answered. I haven't used `getAppHome()`

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, how did you get images to load when using setpage ? Or are you saying its impossible?

Comment: You need to supply a base URL or encode them into the file

Comment: supplying a base url does not work, I have been trying for days, it is not possible to encode them all into one file under my circumstances. Therefore base url is not working in cn1, must be a bug. Base url should be the current directory where the html and its images are stored right ?

Comment: There was a bug in file URL's on the simulator it was fixed in last weeks release. I suggest creating a test case and working from there in a separate question of your own.

Comment: Thanks, yeh its not fixed, I did what you suggested on forum, write my html string to a new file then load that up instead using seturl

Comment: I would need a test case