# Codenameone load HTML from Storage / FileSystemStorage

Tags: codenameone

I've checked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801915/codename-one-webbrowser-loading-html-from-filesystemstorage) but still can't find a solution.

I'm trying to view an offline HTML file. The file can be stored at either `Storage` or `FileSystemStorage`. However, I'm not sure how to obtain a URL for files in `Storage` so I used `FileSystemStorage.getAppHomePath`. The code that I'm using is as shown:

```
    BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
    String appPath = fs.getAppHomePath();
    bc.setURL(appPath + "1.html");
```

where the HTML (and the support files not shown) was downloaded from web using:

```
    Util.downloadUrlToFile("https://google.com", appPath + "1.html", false);
```

The `.cn1/` folder does contain 1.html, but the page was not loaded. The error code is

```
Received exception: File not found
java.lang.Throwable: File not found
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.describeError(WebEngine.java:1463)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1402)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$1200(WebEngine.java:1280)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(WebEngine.java:1267)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2499)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(WebPage.java:2343)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFail(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.notifyDidFail(URLLoader.java:883)
    at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$didFail$104(URLLoader.java:866)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Another approach, with

```
String html  = Util.readToString(fs.openInputStream(appPath + "1.html"));
bc.setPage(html, appPath);
```

can show the html but does not load the supporting file, which is a `.js` file. Copying the `.js` content into the html in a `<script>` tag allows everything to show correctly.

---

I'd like to ask if this behavior is due to any bug in my code, and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Probably not relevant, but I've briefly looked through the code and the `CodenameOneImplementation#setBrowserURL` contains this line, which looks a bit suspicious: 

                InputStream i = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), **url.substring(6))**;

The simulator probably use another implementation tho, as adding a breakpoint there doesn't affect the simulator

Answer (score 0):

The download method is asynchronous so the file isn't there when you invoke the request but is there when you finish.

The reality of what you are trying to do (an offline browser) isn't as simple. You need to not just download the HTML but also fetch all of its dependencies (JavaScript, CSS, images etc.) and save the whole hierarchy locally. Furthermore, you need to do the same for all the dependencies e.g. the CSS and JS files can include files too and those are relative to the servers where they are hosted.

**Update:**

I tried again to reproduce it based on the instructions in the comments and I'm still unable to do that:

```
Form hi = new Form("Browser", new BorderLayout());

BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();
String appPath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath();
bc.setURL(appPath + "1.html");

hi.add(CENTER, bc);

hi.show();
```

I then used the hardcoded file `1.html` in the `.cn1` directory:

```
<html><button>click me</button></html>
```

And it worked:

[image]

Comment: Indeed I've checked that everything is contained in `FileSystemStorage`, and the HTML from `/.cn1` shows without problem in the desktop browser. Even at the second time the simulator is run (when the files are already present), the same `java.lang.Throwable: File not found` is still thrown when calling the `bc#setURL`, so the asynchronous nature or file dependencies is probably not related here

Comment: What are the physical paths? What's the value of appPath? Do you have a directory called `html` in the hierarchy? If so it might be falling into a special case

Comment: Path to the html is `C:\Users\username\.cn1\1.html`, the appPath is `file://home/` and the url feed to the browser that cause a `java.lang.Throwable: File not found` is `file://home/1.html`. No directory was created. A call to `Util.readToString(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream("file://home/1.html")` returned the html as `String` correctly, which can then be displayed by `bc.setPage(html, appPath)`

Comment: Does the user name contain a space in the path or a special none-latin character?

Comment: Can you use `addBrowserNavigationCallback` and log the URL requested there? What's the value you receive?

Comment: `file://c/Users/username/.cn1/1.html` from `addBrowserNavigationCallback`

Comment: Odd. Can you verify that this happens even if you don't download the file and have it there to begin with? Is the file a simple clean HTML with no external dependencies?

Comment: Yes the file is already there. Tried both with / without external dependencies but neither worked (same `File not found`). The html using now is `<html><button>click me</button></html>`

Comment: I tried to reproduce this and failed. Can you take my test case from the edited answer with no download aspect or anything and see if this fails?

Comment: I guess it's ok to show the user name as well as it's not too private
Current code:
`        Form hi = new Form("Welcome", new BorderLayout());`
`        BrowserComponent bc = new BrowserComponent();`
`        bc.addBrowserNavigationCallback(url -> {`
`         System.out.println(url);`
`         return true;`
`        });`
`     bc.setURL(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + "1.html");`
`        hi.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, bc);`
`        hi.show();`

Comment: CMD:
`C:\Users\fu123\.cn1>dir
 Directory of C:\Users\fu123\.cn1

04-Mar-18  02:00 PM    <DIR>          .
04-Mar-18  02:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
02-Jan-18  12:58 AM           753,986 .cn1.7z
03-Mar-18  01:28 PM                38 1.html
20-Feb-18  03:33 AM           702,586 3.html
04-Mar-18  12:21 AM               682 CN1Log__$
03-Mar-18  12:01 PM               219 CN1Preferences
04-Mar-18  12:06 AM    <DIR>          CN1_Cache
20-Feb-18  03:40 AM             1,088 Cookies
`

Comment: I'm now using Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2) to do the test. Codename One revisions is aff721e7f7f4563adbfd9daa21071424853a2683
The Microsoft account name does contains non-latin character, but the path to .cn1 does not. Now try to update the cn1 to see if anything changed

Comment: Did you try my test case on your machine? Does that test case work in a new clean project?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried your test case in a clean project. The same `File not found` was thrown.

Comment: Are you using plugin 4.0? Is the update framework installed and everything is up to date? https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-update-framework.html

Comment: We found the issue: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/24c83e52786a20ee491e5fa3e8485cc3bef9bd09 it should be fixed in next weeks update

Comment: It looks like we have a regression here because I started to get the error in the simulator. On devices it works ok, though.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue in the issue tracker with a test case